# Send attachment by vba in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have this code to send emails but i need to send an Report of access after created, i have this code to send email:

```
 User = Environ$("username")
    emailDC = "email@email.com"

    Dim mess_body As String
        Dim appOutLook As Object
        Dim MailOutLook As Object
        Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With MailOutLook

            .To = emailDC
            .Subject = User
            .HTMLBody = "Try access to file"

            .DeleteAfterSubmit = True   'This would let Outlook send th note without storing it in your sent bin
            .Send
            End With
            'MsgBox MailOutLook.Body
            Exit Sub
email_error:
            MsgBox "An error was encountered." & vbCrLf & "The error message is: " & Err.Description
            Resume Error_out
Error_out:
```

But i need to send this with a report in .pdf

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347847/attach-two-files-in-a-mail

Comment: Not duplicate, i dont want to send files, i want send a internal report of access

Comment: How would you do it manually?

Comment: right now i have the report and save as pdf and send by email, but i want this process automatic, by vba

Comment: Okay, the suggested duplicate tells you how to attach a PDF to the e-mail. So, really, your question is, how do I first save the report as PDF. Is that correct? If so, you should edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Save the Report as a .pdf

Use the [`DoCmd.OutputTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx) method to generate the pdf :

```
DoCmd.OutputTo _
    acOutputReport, "Your Report Name", _
    acFormatPDF, "A:\Temporary\Place\To\Store\Report.pdf", _
    False,"", 0, acExportQualityPrint
```

MailItem has an `Attachments` property that allows you to [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx) attachments :

```
With MailOutLook
    '...
    .Attachments.Add(yourReportPath)
    '...
End With
```

Comment: "(yourReportPath)"
This is my report name? if yes, dont work.    Is a report inside Access, i want send a report went i close it.

Comment: you need to pass the path to your report pdf like : .Add("C:\Documents\Report.pdf")

Comment: But the report is on access not external

Comment: check the edited answer for how to generate the pdf for your report