# Adding multiple attachments to a single email using outlook VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook, email-attachments

EDIT

```
Sub CreateEmail(Subject As String, Body As String, ToSend As String, CCs As String, FilePathtoAdd As String)

 Dim OlApp As Object
 Dim OlMail As MailItem
 Dim ToRecipient As Variant
 Dim CcRecipient As Variant
 Dim Attachments() As String
 Dim i As Integer


 Set OlApp = Application
 Set OlMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


 OlMail.Recipients.Add ToSend

 OlMail.Subject = Subject
 OlMail.Body = Body
 OlMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "mailbox"



 If FilePath1 <> "" Then

If FilePathtoAdd <> "" Then
    Attachments = Split(FilePathtoAdd, ",")
    For i = LBound(Attachments) To UBound(Attachments)
        If Attachments(i) <> "" Then
            OMail.Attachments.Add Trim(Attachments(i))
        End If
    Next i
End If


End If

 OlMail.Display 'change this to OlMail.Send if you just want to send it without previewing it

 End Sub
Sub EmailIt()
CreateEmail "This is Subject", "Body", "To", "CC", "C:\Users\b\Desktop\NFM\Export\0418 LSN " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xls", "C:\Users\b\Desktop\NFM\Export\0418 Backorder " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xls"

End Sub
```

I'm using the code below, in outlook vba, to create an email, attach a file, and send the email. It works fine, except I can't figure out how to add multiple attachments to a single email? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CreateEmail(Subject As String, Body As String, ToSend As String, CCs As String, FilePathtoAdd As String)

 'write the default Outlook contact name list to the active worksheet

 Dim OlApp As Object
 Dim OlMail As MailItem
 Dim ToRecipient As Variant
 Dim CcRecipient As Variant

'Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 'Set OlMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 Set OlApp = Application
 Set OlMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 'For Each ToRecipient In Array("mba.szabist@gmail.com", "mba.szabist@gmail.com", "mba.szabist@gmail.com")
 'OlMail.Recipients.Add ToRecipient
 OlMail.Recipients.Add ToSend
 'Next ToRecipient


'fill in Subject field
 OlMail.Subject = Subject
 OlMail.Body = Body
 OlMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "email.com"


 'Add the active workbook as an attachment
' OlMail.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Sentence Correction\Comparisons.pdf"
 If FilePathtoAdd <> "" Then
    OlMail.Attachments.Add FilePathtoAdd
End If
 'Display the message
 OlMail.Display 'change this to OlMail.Send if you just want to send it without previewing it

 End Sub
Sub EmailIt()
CreateEmail "This is Subject", "Body", "email.com", " ", "C:\Users\b\Desktop\NFM\Export\0418 LSN " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xls"


End Sub
```

Comment: Already asked and answered here: [Attach two files in a mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347847/attach-two-files-in-a-mail)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
 Olmail.attachments.add secondpath
```

If you put the attachment paths in a comma delimited string and pass it as "FilePathToAdd" then you can do this:

```
Dim Attachments() As String
Dim i As Integer

If FilePathToAdd <> "" Then
    Attachments = Split(FilePathToAdd, ",")
    For i = LBound(Attachments) To UBound(Attachments)
        If Attachments(i) <> "" Then
            OlMail.Attachments.Add Trim(Attachments(i))
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I'm still having difficulties getting this to work. I receive the error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment." I think this is because it is looking for another argument in the sub. If I insert another ADD function, like suggested in the other reply, I can get it to work, but the problem with that is not all of the emails will have the same number of attachments. Your code seems like it is what i am looking for. Maybe I am just inserting the second file path incorrectly? I edited my post with the code inserted, is this correct? Thanks again!

Comment: What line is giving you this error?  What are the values of the variables at this point?  What does the "Filepathtoadd" string look like?  It needs to be comma delimited so "Mypath/File1.xls,Mypath2/File2.xls, Mypath3/File3.xls...."

Comment: Okay, I messed with it a bit, It looks like i had an extra " in the string. Now I'm getting Run-Time error '424' Object Required on line `OMail.Attachments.Add Trim(Attachments(i))` but the filepath is correct and the file is there.
My "filepathtoadd" string is `"C:\Users\balljt\Desktop\NFM\Export\0418 LSN " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xls, C:\Users\balljt\Desktop\NFM\Export\0418 Backorder " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xls"
`
Maybe the date format is throwing it off?

Comment: It grabs the single file fine with `OlMail.Attachments.Add FilePathtoAdd`

and `C:\Users\balljt\Desktop\NFM\Export\0418 LSN " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xls"`

Comment: Does this error out the first time it runs through or the second time? Debug.print attachments(i) when the error happens and make sure that the path is valid. It could be happening on the second file. That error occurs when the file doesn't exist...

Comment: It errors out the first time. Debug.print attachments(i) returns C:\Users\balljt\Desktop\NFM\Export\0418 LSN 03-20-15.xls - which is correct.

I copy and paste the file path returned into a Run dialog box and the file opens. I'm at a loss as to why this error is occurring. Thanks for your continued help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: I was wrong, the problem was a misspelling on my part.  Change "OMail.Add" To "OlMail.Add" and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines from your code add the attachment:

```
 'Add the active workbook as an attachment
 ' OlMail.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Sentence Correction\Comparisons.pdf"
 If FilePathtoAdd <> "" Then
    OlMail.Attachments.Add FilePathtoAdd
 End If
```

You just need to call the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Attachment class as many times as you need to add attachments specifying different file paths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got this to work, but the problem is not all of the emails have the same number of attachments. The macro fails if a path is missing. Is there a way around this?