# Add Multiple Attachments based on Comma Separated list in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to attach multiple files based on the contents in cells from Column B.

```
Sub EmailTest()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row 'change worksheet as needed

For i = 2 To lastRow

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

    With OutLookMailItem
        .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Body = "Testing an email macro, just delete me"
        On Error Resume Next
        Attach.Add [F2] & Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xlsx" 'change cell reference in brackets as needed
        .Display
        On Error GoTo 0
        '.Send
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

I found the below link and I made a few unsuccessful attempts.

[Adding multiple attachments to a single email using outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154982/adding-multiple-attachments-to-a-single-email-using-outlook-vba)

In Column B I want to enter Book2,Book3 and the code to understand that is two different attachments. It is possible there can be more attachments which is why I want to go with some variation of Attachments = Split.

In Cell F2 I have a concatenate formula that allows the user to change the file path the code references without understanding VBA.

Comment: Do you have a cell containing the list of attachments as a comma separated list? This is what you need to pick up (or create) and then split and loop over to add as attachments.

Comment: And do you want to send just one e-mail with multiple attachments? It would seem not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use one more loop to go through all names in a cell, in order to get array of these names, I used `Spli()` method.

```
'declare variable att the beginning
Dim att as Variant
'loop, also you have to enter separator here, I used ","
For Each att in Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
    Attach.Add [F2] & att & ".xlsx" 'change cell reference in brackets as needed
Next
```

Comment: Assuming that has the comma separated list